# MQL4 Trade Is Disabled

Tags: mql4, trading, broker, metatrader4

I've been using `MQL4` for a couple of days now, but recently I've been getting the error message:

```
(133) trade is disabled
```

when performing an order.

From reading the different forums, I understand the common belief is that I have to talk to my broker to enable *Expert Advisors*, but trading DID work for me (on and off) until now!

Has anyone else encountered this error - NOT relating to enable EA from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No need to talk to your Broker

MetaTrader4 Server side has nothing to do with this.

### Check your localhost Terminal settings

There might be several reasons, why the EA was working ( "DID work" as you post it )
and still you get an error.

An `MT4.Terminal.Profile` change can also cause this to happen.

An `MT4.Terminal.LogAnotherUser` change can also cause this to happen.

An `MT4.Terminal.Graph` change of { `Symbol` | `Period` } can also cause this to happen.

**Check `Tools` > `Options` > `Expert Advisor` [TAB]** for active values in respective check-boxes for all the above.

Check, if you are correctly logged-on to a **correct** ( not canceled ) **trading account**.

Check, if your connection is green / working

Check, if your trading Symbol has active market ( open trading hours )

If still in troubles, send a few **`OrderSend()`**-s with `PrintScreen`-s and copy responses from Log-File & post here.

Comment: Thanks! I have been messing around with the graphs (and time periods), that might have something to do with it... I'll look into it :)

Comment: @user3666197 - Sometimes you do need to talk to your broker. In my case the symbol I was trying to trade was being expired, so they only allowed closing trades on that symbol - not allowing new ones to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it cause of abnormal looping by your Expert Advisor. You may see at journal tab, if it created too many orders or modify orders at a moment of time, server could significantly overloaded and caused lags and malfunctions. Therefore, broker should disable it.

If so, you should fix your EA first, then let your broker know that as consideration for asking them to reenable your account.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem using a Broker-configured account, with hedging enabled.

I had been running on DEMO-practice, with no problems, but when I switched to the LIVE-account, **`error 133`** happened.

It was because the trade server that it was linked in was the GMT-5 one, and only the GMT+2 server is allowed for a hedging account.

Server was changed, started working no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your broker that the symbol hasn't been disabled. They do this sometimes when they introduce a new symbols to replace old ones.

A disabled symbol will still show up in MT4 to allow users to close trades in the symbol ( but you get the above mentioned error, if you try to open a new order )

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that same error code when I tried to modify the *Stoploss* of an already closed order.